# Output list items as ls does

Tags: format, max, tcl, width

I'm trying to output something that resembles as ls output. The ls command outputs like this:

```
file1.txt   file3.txt    file5.txt
file2.txt   file4.txt
```

But I this sample list:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

to appear as:

```
a e i m q u y
b f j n r v z
c g k o s w 
d h l p t x
```

In that case, it gave 7 columns which is fine, but I wanted up to 8 columns max. Next the following list:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w
```

will have to show as:

```
a d g j m p s v
b e h k n q t w
c f i l o r u
```

And "a b c d e f g h" will have to show as is because it is already 8 columns in 1 line, but:

```
a b c d e f g h i
```

will show as:

```
a c e g i 
b d f h
```

And:

```
a b c d e f g h i j

a c e g i 
b d f h j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

proc columnize {lst {columns 8}} {
    set len [llength $lst]
    set nrows [expr {int(ceil($len / (0.0 + $columns)))}]
    set cols [list]
    for {set n 0} {$n < $len} {incr n $nrows} {
        lappend cols [lrange $lst $n [expr {$n + $nrows - 1}]]
    }
    for {set n 0} {$n < $nrows} {incr n} {
        set row [list]
        foreach col $cols {
            lappend row [lindex $col $n]
        }
        puts [join $row " "]
    }
}


columnize {a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z}
puts ----
columnize {a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w}
puts ----
columnize {a b c d e f g h}
puts ----
columnize {a b c d e f g h i}
puts ----
columnize {a b c d e f g h i j}
```

The `columnize` function first figures out how many rows are needed with a simple division of the length of the list by the number of columns requested, then splits the list up into chunks of that length, one per column, and finally iterates through those sublists extracting the current row's element for each column, and prints the row out as a space-separated list.

Comment: A fancier version would also take a line length, and figure out the width of the columns so everything is nicely aligned when using elements of different lengths. That is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I believe you can get the terminal line length in 8.7 using `chan configure stdin -winsize`. Or at the very least it is *supposed* to be there and working...

Comment: @DonalFellows Nice. I just use `exec tput cols` with a fallback to a default value right now.